# Can a British citizen work in the UK without an NI number?

Tags: united-kingdom

My brother acquired his British citizenship/Passport abroad, he never stepped a foot in the UK before, he is coming to settle in the UK next week, can he work instantly the same day he arrives or he will have to wait till he gets an NI number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of. He can work, but he will be emergency taxed. This is a higher rate than normal tax.

Apply for an NIN as soon as he lands: https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number

Comment: It isn't necessarily a "higher rate," but with an emergency tax code only your own personal allowance is tax-free. Unless the OP's brother has a wife and any children, he probably won't have any other tax-free allowances or sources of UK-taxable income anyway. The tax situation would be worse if he takes more than one part-time job, for example, because without a NI number there is no way to track exactly where his allowances are being deducted, so *all* his employers have to assume they are being deducted by someone else! In any case, he should apply for an NI number *as soon as possible.*